# Freeze and crash on lockscreen Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: suspend, asus, freeze, lock-screen, session

I have a an issue on 20.04

Ubuntu freezes or logs out of the Ubuntu on Wayland session, if it has been suspended.
Also freezes on a few occasions of unplugging the USB type C charger or USB type C hub.
After both events the system needs a restart by power button.

Additional info:

- Docker containers are running in the background, around 3-4, started by docker-composer.
- BIOS version 304, up to date version.
- RAM usage usually 80-90%.
- 8GB RAM, 10GB swap
- Slack is running always.
- PhpStorm is tunning always.
- Smartgit is running always.
- A Chromium window with a few tabs is running always.

Gnome extensions enabled:

- Dash to dock
- System-momitor
- Skip window notification

Log after suspend freeze:

journalctl -b -1 | tail -50

```
[System monitor] applet enabling done
jún 09 11:49:41 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: loading default theme (Adwaita)
jún 09 11:49:41 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA dbus-daemon[5921]: [session uid=1000 pid=5921] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
jún 09 11:49:41 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA org.freedesktop.FileManager1[31475]: Failed to register: Unable to acquire bus name 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
jún 09 11:49:41 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA dbus-daemon[5921]: [session uid=1000 pid=5921] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.FileManager1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.FileManager1 exited with status 1
jún 09 11:49:42 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: Error connecting to Nautilus
jún 09 11:49:42 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: Gio.DBusError: Hiba a StartServiceByName hívásakor ehhez: org.freedesktop.FileManager1: Process org.freedesktop.FileManager1 exited with status 1
jún 09 11:49:42 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
jún 09 11:49:42 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
jún 09 11:49:42 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
jún 09 11:49:42 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
jún 09 11:49:42 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
jún 09 11:49:42 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
jún 09 11:49:42 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
jún 09 11:49:42 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
jún 09 11:49:42 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
jún 09 11:49:42 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA chromium_chromium.desktop[8713]: [8713:8713:0609/114942.933735:ERROR:edid_parser.cc(102)] Too short EDID data: manufacturer id
jún 09 11:49:47 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA systemd[1]: Starting Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service...
jún 09 11:49:47 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA sh[31520]: laptop-mode: Battery polling disabled
jún 09 11:49:47 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA systemd[1]: lmt-poll.service: Succeeded.
jún 09 11:49:47 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA systemd[1]: Finished Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service.
jún 09 11:50:00 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA systemd-resolved[2659]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
jún 09 11:50:02 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA chromium_chromium.desktop[8981]: [8981:30855:0609/115002.210044:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(637)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for secure.fruitflan.com failed:
jún 09 11:50:02 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA chromium_chromium.desktop[8981]: ----- Certificate i=0 (CN=*.fruitflan.com,OU=Domain Control Validated) -----
jún 09 11:50:02 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA chromium_chromium.desktop[8981]: ERROR: Time is after notAfter
jún 09 11:50:02 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA chromium_chromium.desktop[8981]: [8981:8985:0609/115002.210213:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(959)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -201
jún 09 11:50:09 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
jún 09 11:50:15 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: 0x220002a: frame_complete callback never occurred for frame 126829
jún 09 11:50:15 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: 0x220002a: frame_complete callback never occurred for frame 126828
jún 09 11:50:15 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: 0x220002a: frame_complete callback never occurred for frame 126827
jún 09 11:50:15 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: 0x220002a: frame_complete callback never occurred for frame 126826
jún 09 11:50:48 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: 0x220002a: frame_complete callback never occurred for frame 127310
jún 09 11:50:52 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA systemd-resolved[2659]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
jún 09 11:50:52 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA systemd-resolved[2659]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
jún 09 11:50:53 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA systemd-logind[3445]: Power key pressed.
jún 09 11:50:53 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA NetworkManager[3415]: <info>  [1591696253.0518] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
jún 09 11:50:53 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA NetworkManager[3415]: <info>  [1591696253.0519] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jún 09 11:50:53 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA NetworkManager[3415]: <info>  [1591696253.0528] device (F8:38:80:7E:1C:BA): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jún 09 11:50:53 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA NetworkManager[3415]: <info>  [1591696253.0539] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
jún 09 11:50:53 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA whoopsie[4141]: [11:50:53] offline
jún 09 11:50:53 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: Source ID 216141 was not found when attempting to remove it
jún 09 11:50:53 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: Source ID 216272 was not found when attempting to remove it
jún 09 11:50:53 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: Source ID 216319 was not found when attempting to remove it
jún 09 11:50:53 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA gnome-shell[6052]: [System monitor] applet disable
jún 09 11:50:53 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA update-notifier[7545]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
jún 09 11:50:53 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA update-notifier[7545]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
jún 09 11:50:54 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
jún 09 11:50:54 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
jún 09 11:50:54 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA systemd-sleep[31811]: Suspending system...
jún 09 11:50:54 hunguard-ZenBook-S-UX391UA kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
```

Answer (score 0):

### For the freezes when suspend:

I got the same issue and fixed it updating my `/etc/default/grub` file adding `i915.enable_dc=0` at variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

Then `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

*Why did I disable power-saving? Because in my case, all C-States had an issue (did not wake up properly after `systemctl suspend`. Maybe one of `1`, `2`, `3` or `4` may work in someone else case.*

#### For the crash plug/unplug:

I **updated my bios** (very easy, btw) with the last version **307**: https://www.asus.com/supportonly/ux391ua/helpdesk_bios/ **it solved a lot of issues** I used to have with this (shitty) computer.